# Show/edit a file on onedrive with microsoft graph

Tags: html, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive, microsoft-graph-sdks

I want to use a json file on onedrive to save and edit the data there. I copy this here from microsoft graph:
*[https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/search(q='finance')?select=name,id,webUrl](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/search(q=%27finance%27)?select=name,id,webUrl)*
But this don't work, if I want to log this into the console. It's my first time to use an api. Hope of help here.

Answer (score 0):

if you are just starting with Microsoft Graph, take a look to Graph Explorer https://aka.ms/ge. That is online playground where you can try your queries or explore lots of examples for Microsoft Graph.

To work with files in OneDrive, you would need to work with DriveItem entity: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/driveitem?view=graph-rest-1.0

To work with DriveItem metadata, you can perform UpdateItem https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http where you create a JSON collection of all properties of the item that need to be updated, like this

```
PATCH /me/drive/items/{item-id}
Content-type: application/json

{
  "name": "new-file-name.docx"
}
```

To work with DriveItem contents, you would need to perform Upload operation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-put-content?view=graph-rest-1.0

Here are two examples from documentation:

Uploading a new file

```
PUT /me/drive/root:/FolderA/FileB.txt:/content
Content-Type: text/plain

The contents of the file goes here.
```

Updating an existing file

```
PUT /me/drive/items/{item-id}/content
Content-Type: text/plain

The contents of the file goes here.
```

Comment: Ok, but where to I have to login into my microsoft account?